# Grading java program with policies

Tags: java

The grading policies are

2 quizzes 10 points

1 midterm exam and one final exam, each graded on the basis of 100 points

the final exam counts for 50% of the grade, the midterm counts for 25%, and the 2 quizzes together count for a total of 25%.

a letter grade is also suppose to be given

this was given by the instructor

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assign7{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{



    Scanner myIn = new Scanner( new File("scores.txt") );



    System.out.println( myIn.nextLine() +"  avg  "+"letter");

    while( myIn.hasNext() ){
       name = myIn.Next();
       q1 = myIn.nextInt();
       q2 = myIn.nextInt();
       m = myIn.nextInt();
       f = myIn.nextInt();
       Record myR = new Record( name, q1,q2,m,f);
       System.out.println(myR);

    } 
  }
}
```

and this is what i came up with so far however i keep getting three error messages

Assign7.java:28; errror: illegal start of expression 
public String toString(){

Assign7.java:28; errror: ';' expected
public String toString(){

Assign7.java:33: error: reached end of file while parsing
}

Could anybody tell me how to fix this errors please (this is my code)

```
class Assign7{
  private double finalScore;
  private double private_quiz1;
  private double private_quiz2;
  private double private_midTerm;
  private double private_final;
  private final char grade;


  public Assign7(double finalScore){
    private_quiz1 = 1.25;
    private_quiz2 = 1.25;
    private_midTerm = 0.25;
    private_final = 0.50;

        if (finalScore >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        } else if (finalScore >= 80) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (finalScore >= 70) {
            grade = 'C';
        } else if (finalScore>= 60) {
            grade = 'D';
        } else {
            grade = 'F';


  public String toString(){
    return finalScore+":"+private_quiz1+":"+private_quiz2+":"+private_midTerm+":"+private_final;

  }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? He detailed the error and provided relevant code such that we could figure out the answer very quickly.

Comment: @Justin: Snootiness, basically. It got my +1

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a `}` to close out the declaration of `public Assign7` as well as your last `if` statement.

```
public Assign7(double finalScore){
    private_quiz1 = 1.25;
    private_quiz2 = 1.25;
    private_midTerm = 0.25;
    private_final = 0.50;

    if (finalScore >= 90) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if (finalScore >= 80) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if (finalScore >= 70) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if (finalScore>= 60) {
        grade = 'D';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
    } // <===== ADD THIS
} // <============= ADD THIS
```

Other answers give advice on ensuring you always have matching braces to begin with.  Those are solid answers as well.

Comment: now my instructors code is giving me a bunch of error messages how can i fix that

Comment: @ChristopherBerman: Search for my answers to the Homework tag.  You will see that I always give a conceptual hint rather than the answer, if the OP is missing a concept.  Mismatching braces doesn't really fall under the category of "concept" for me, so I helped him get along with his learning.

Comment: @ChristopherBerman: Feel free to remove your downvote then if you so choose :-)

Comment: I tried, but I apparently can't change my vote unless the answer is edited. Stick in another sentence and I will. =p

Comment: @EricJ. can you help me with one last question

Comment: @pasito15: If you have a different question, please post a new question to the site.  I'll be glad to answer it there :-)

Comment: @EricJ.  i did post a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316953/grading-java-program-policies

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace on your else.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Assign7{
  private double finalScore;
  private double private_quiz1;
  private double private_quiz2;
  private double private_midTerm;
  private double private_final;
  private final char grade;


  public Assign7(double finalScore){
    private_quiz1 = 1.25;
    private_quiz2 = 1.25;
    private_midTerm = 0.25;
    private_final = 0.50;

        if (finalScore >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        } else if (finalScore >= 80) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (finalScore >= 70) {
            grade = 'C';
        } else if (finalScore>= 60) {
            grade = 'D';
        } else {
            grade = 'F';
}
```

}

```
  public String toString(){
    return finalScore+":"+private_quiz1+":"+private_quiz2+":"+private_midTerm+":"+private_final;

  }
}
```

Comment: my instructors code is getting a whole bunch of error messages how can i fix that

Comment: @Christopher All i did was add two curly brackets.. If this is completing someones homework the he has some easy homework. And you did the same thing..